# Configuration section not allowed to be set below application - Error Code 0x80070021

Tags: asp.net

supposedly godaddy did a cache refresh, which I would not think change any basic parms or website setup but now 2 applications don't  run

found this post:

`0x80070021 Server Error in Application "application name"
HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
HRESULT: 0x80070021`

Description of HRESULT

`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
This problem can occur when the specified portion of the IIS configuration file is locked at a higher configuration level. To resolve this problem, unlock the specified section, or do not use it at that level. For more information on configuration locking, see How to Use Locking in IIS 7.0 Configuration.`

**I don't know of any config files above my app and I thought when I have specified my app directory as the app root how could there be any higher config files anyway?**

unless there is some other problem cause some body can suggest. called godaddy no help there, they are suggesting some how might site is hacked which is really far fetched

[image]